# Finding the time since the last time you pressed a button in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, scope

I'm pretty new to Java and Android Studio, so forgive any noobishness that I give off. Right now I have a button, and I want to find out the time since the last time you pressed that button when you do end up pressing it again, or if it's your first time pressing the button the time since boot. I know how to do most of this, it's just that I can't find a way to store the exact time of when you press the button for future use.

```
public class FightScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fight_screen);

    final Button fightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fightButton);
    final TextView timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeText);
    final long bootTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

    fightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - bootTime;
            timeText.setText(String.valueOf(timeElapsed));
        }
    });
}
}
```

I left out some bits that have absolutely nothing to do with my question.
This block of code finds the time from when you booted up the activity to when you press the button. I was just wondering how I'd be able to return a variable from the onClick function into my future iterations of it. Something like making a global variable lastButtonPressTime and using that in place of bootTime when applicable, so that this code block does what I actuallly want.

Edit: This isn't a duplicate of that other post since I'm not trying to use the Timer class. I want to figure out how to do it through finding differences in times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show elapsed time since pressing a button in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548947/show-elapsed-time-since-pressing-a-button-in-android?rq=1)?

Comment: The first answer on the possible duplicate doesn't use the Timer class, so I think liquidsystem is still correct here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class FightScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {  
   long lastClickTime = 0;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_fight_screen);

      final Button fightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fightButton);
      final TextView timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeText);
      final long bootTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
      lastClickTime = bootTime;
      fightButton.setOnClickListener(this);// the listener is this class now


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        Long timeNow = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        Long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime;   
        lastClickTime = timeNow;
        timeText.setText(String.valueOf(timeElapsed));
    }



}
```

implement `View.OnClickListener` and override the `onClick()` method as shown above, it is basically a different way of handling events.If have more than one View then in the `onClick()` you can check the view id through `v.getId()` to determine what to do with click depending on the sending view

Comment: I can't do that though, since in order for me to be able to use lastClickTime in an inner class I need to make it final. This, in turn, restricts me from modifying it in said inner class.

Comment: have a look at this link  http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/14/implementing-listeners-in-your-android-java-application/

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, my full, unabridged code is this:http://pastebin.com/t4yrjS9X . It doesn't have any errors, it just crashes when I enter the activity. "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference."

Comment: link to your code doesn't work, but most probably your button is not initialised. Are you sure the fightButton is in (R.layout.activity_fight_screen)??!

Comment: Weird, the link does work for me. Try http://pastebin.com/t4yrjS9X instead. Yes, fightButton is in the activity. The problem probably lies within my actual code, here I reuploaded it: http://pastebin.com/4LRauzgg . Both should work, maybe try copying the URL into your browser. Thanks!

Comment: can you please post the trace of the crash here?

Comment: move all calls to findViewById() inside the onCreate method. because before that it is not initialised yet.